# Laravel 4 Auth::attempt using either email or username and password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In laravel for login attempt I generally use something like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $usernameinput, 'password' => $password), true))
{
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

Basically `$usernameinput` will check with `email` from my table.

I was thinking to do it in a different way, like there is `email`, `username` and `password` in my table. `$usernameinput`  can be either `email`  or `username` field in my table.

How can I `Auth::attempt` with a condition like:

```
(email==$usernameinput OR username==$usernameinput) AND password == $password
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, you could simply check if `$usernameinput` matches an email pattern and if it does, use the `email` field, else use the `username` field. This sounds reasonable because, well, you really shouldn't have any e-mail in your database that doesn't match the pattern. Something like this:

```
$field = filter_var($usernameinput, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';

if (Auth::attempt([$field => $usernameinput, 'password' => $password], true)) {
    // ...
}
```

The other option is to extend `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` adding the wanted functionality and setting it as the `auth` component, in a new service provider.

Comment: Great , It's simple solution that I wanted :-)

Comment: @CodeDemon It should.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done something like this

```
$field = Validator::make(array('email' => $usernameinput, array('email' => 'email'))->passes() ? 'email' : 'username';
if (Auth::attempt(array($field => $usernameinput, 'password' => $password), true)) {
    return Redirect::intended('profile');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Users could use an email field as their username, and it might not match the email they used for the email field.  Safer to attempt authentication twice:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email_or_username'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        )) ||
    Auth::attempt(array(
            'username'     => Input::get('email_or_username'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        ))) {
    // SUCCESS
} else {
    // FAILURE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete working solution: (Tested with Laravel 5.3)

Just add this method(or we can say override) into **app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $usernameinput = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $field = filter_var($usernameinput, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';

        if (Auth::attempt([$field => $usernameinput, 'password' => $password])) {
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        } else {
            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }
```