# allow both username and email in login laravel 5

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I use laravel's 5 built in authentication for login. im spending hours finding where is the database query located at that has been use when login, I want to both allow email and username is the email box. Anyone knows where that database query located at? anyone knows how to allow both username and password on the authentication.

PS: to sharpen the details, I just want the user to allow them to login both username and email.

PS: again! Im running on laravel 5 not 4!

Comment: might be wrong but thing you'd need to roll your own, I'd be surprised if the built in auth did this out of the box

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [Laravel 4 Auth::attempt using either email or username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694983/laravel-4-authattempt-using-either-email-or-username-and-password)

Comment: ... and what happens if I choose someone else's email as my username?

Comment: @SimonSvensson: there is a password for each username or email, it just what I want to do is to let the user login in either username or email and there corresponding password for there account

Comment: @CodeDemon, which works until I manage to block out a site administrator since I choose "admin@site.com" as my username, and "sisve@awesome.com" as email. That means that the admin, which is used to login with email, will match by username and get a "bad password"-message, while I still login with my "sisve@awesome.com"-email.

Answer (score 1):

Define both a login and an password input in your form then the request should look like :

```
public function authorize() {
    return true;
}


public function rules()
{
    return [
       'login' => 'required',
       'password' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Then your login function should look like :

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $field = filter_var($request->input('login'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
    $request->merge([$field => $request->input('login')]);

    if ($this->auth->attempt($request->only($field, 'password')))
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return redirect('/login')->withErrors([
        'error' => 'You email/username or password combination is wrong.',
    ]);
}
```

**This is an optimized version because instead of doing 2 attemps to verify the credentials for both : if is a username or if is a password, laravel will do the work with verifying if the given data points to an email login or username.**

Comment: is this will work in laravel 5? where to put this or inject this?

Comment: Open cmd on windows or terminal on linux and "cd location/to/laravel/framework" and then "php artisan make:request LoginRequest" and put there after authorization function in validation function the first block of code from my answer. And the second block of code you need to inject inside the controller that you want to do the login, after of course you link them in routes.php . I recommend you to read the documentation first.

Comment: I ran into a problem where it threw an error because a Request was being passed into login(), and not a LoginRequest. What say you?

Comment: This answer is a little outdated, i recommend you to check out the documentation.