# Login with either email or username

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel 5, I use its built in login stuff and yes I can login with email and password, everything works perfectly. Now, I created a new column named `username` and filled it with my desired username in the `users table (the table containing the login stuff). How can I login with either email or username and password?

I found this from **AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php**:

```php
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                ]);
}
```

Any suggestion, recommendations, clues, ideas, help to tweak the above code so that I could login with either username or email and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#authenticating-users) states that it is possible to use a custom column. So if you want to authenticate with a username you could use the following:

```
this->auth->attempt(['username' => 'the_username', 'password' => 'the_password', 
$request->has('remember'));
```

That would require you to do a second call to Auth::attempt if the first one fails.

You could also take the approach that was answered to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694983/laravel-4-authattempt-using-either-email-or-username-and-password) (Credit to Raphael for his excellent solution:

```
$usernameinput = $request->input('email');
$field = filter_var($usernameinput, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';

if (Auth::attempt(array($field => $usernameinput, 'password' => $password),
    $request->has('remember'))) {
    // ...
}
```